# Querying timedelta column in pandas, and filtering rows

Tags: pandas, filtering, timedelta

I have a column of timedelta in pandas. It is in the format x days 00:00:00. I want to filter out and flag the rows which have a value >=30 minutes. I have no clue how to do that using pandas. I tried booleans and if statements but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

You can convert `timedelta`s to seconds by [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and compare with scalar:

```
df = df[df['col'].dt.total_seconds() < 30]
```

Or compare with `Timedelta`:

```
df = df[df['col'] < pd.Timedelta(30, unit='s')]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':pd.to_timedelta(['25:10:01','00:01:20','00:00:20'])})
print (df)
              col
0 1 days 01:10:01
1 0 days 00:01:20
2 0 days 00:00:20

df = df[df['col'].dt.total_seconds() < 30]
print (df)
       col
2 00:00:20
```